# How to manage i18n routing in next.js to use slash instead of dash

Tags: next.js, i18next, next-i18next

I have a website that have multiple countries and each country has more than one locale
here is my `next-i18next.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en-eg',
    locales: ['en-br', 'en-eg', 'en-ke', 'pt-br', 'pt-eg', 'pt-ke', 'en', 'pt'],
    localeDetection: false,
  },
  lowerCaseLng: true,
  fallbackLng: {
    'en-br': ['en'],
    'en-eg': ['en'],
    'en-ke': ['en'],
    'pt-br': ['pt'],
    'pt-eg': ['pt'],
    'pt-ke': ['pt'],
  },
};
```

the desired behavior instead of `/{language}-{country}/:path` to be `{country}/{language/:path` I wonder is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) in `next.config.js` to map the desired URL format to a different destination path that actually exists.

```js
//next.config.js

module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            // Add an entry for each locale that needs to be mapped
            {
                source: '/br/pt/:path*',
                destination: '/pt-br/:path*'
            },
            // Other locales rewrites here
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I also tried using the `locale: false` option. Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the game, but had the same issue and managed to figure it out, so leaving this for others who might have this problem.

Like juliomalves' said, you have to use `rewrites` to do this, but slightly different.

If you checkout the docs for rewrites (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) you will notice it has a section with `beforeFiles`, `afterFiles`, and `fallback`. We need to use the `beforeFiles` to make sure it does the rewrite at this stage.

Then you can also make a redirect from the `/en-US` route to `/us/en` route, which I have included in the snippet. Here you need `locale: false` for this to match correctly.

```
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en-US", "nl-NL"],
    defaultLocale: ["en-US"],
  },
  async rewrites() {
    return {
      beforeFiles: [
        {
          source: "/us/en/:path*",
          destination: "/en-US/:path*",
        },
        {
          source: "/nl/nl/:path*",
          destination: "/nl-NL/:path*",
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/en-US/:path*",
        destination: "/us/en/:path*",
        permanent: false,
        locale: false,
      },
      {
        source: "/nl-NL/:path*",
        destination: "/nl/nl/:path*",
        permanent: false,
        locale: false,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Hope it helps!