# Nextjs Internationalized route, double parameter

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, url-routing

I would like to have my website url like that /[cc]/[lang]. The first part would be the country, the second one the current language. The main problem is that I have no idea how to create the second parameter

```
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en", "de"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) to handle the mapping? You could have an object for each country/locale combination that would map to the right localised route, e.g. `{ source: '/us/en/:path*', destination: '/en/:path*' }`. Similar to what's suggested in [How to manage i18n routing in next.js to use slash instead of dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70157802/how-to-manage-i18n-routing-in-next-js-to-use-slash-instead-of-dash).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a similar issue to: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/32295 try using the middleware provided there:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/;

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const nextUrl =
    req.url.split('/')[1] === 'next' || req.url.split('/')[1] === '_next';
  if (!PUBLIC_FILE.test(req.nextUrl.pathname) && !nextUrl) {
    const [_, language, country] = req.url.split('/');
    const newUrl = req.nextUrl;
    newUrl.pathname = `/${language.toUpperCase()}/${country}/<your url>`;
    newUrl.locale = `${language}-${country.toUpperCase()}`;
    return NextResponse.rewrite(newUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes middleware could be solution for this case, but unfortunately I have to use nextjs11